# How to get the updated data after clicking back button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, webbrowser-control, cart

I am doing a task on a cart in which when I click on an add_cart button. It should show the total number of items present in the cart on the cart icon. It shows the right count after I add items to the cart but the problem comes when I click on the cart_details page and then I press the back button. It shows old numbers even before I added items to the cart.

```
$('body').on('click', '.cart', function () {
            id = $(this).attr("id");
            
            website_id = id.replace("cart_", "");
            advertiser_id = <?php echo $advertiser_id; ?>;
            cart_icon_class = $(this).find("img").attr("class");
            
            if(cart_icon_class == "blank_cart"){
                action = "add";
            }else{
                action = "delete";
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "{{ route('cartstore') }}",
                data: {id: website_id, advertiser_id: advertiser_id, action:action, website_id:website_id},
                dataType: 'json',

                success: function (data) {
                    if(action == "add"){
                    // console.log(data);
                    $("#cart_span").text(data['carts']);
                    $("#wishlist_span").text(data['wish']);
                    $(".box no-border").hide();
                    $("#cart-success").show();


                    $("#cart_icon_" + data["website_id"]).attr("src","{{URL::asset('assets/images/fas-fa-shopping-cart.png')}}");
                    $("#cart_icon_" + data["website_id"]).removeClass('blank_cart');
                    $("#cart_icon_" + data["website_id"]).addClass('filled_cart');

                    $("#wish_icon_" + data["website_id"]).removeClass('fas fa-heart');
                    $("#wish_icon_" + data["website_id"]).addClass('far fa-heart');
                    
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('#cart-success').hide();
                    }, 1500);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    // console.log(data);
                    $("#cart_span").text(data['carts']);
                    $("#wishlist_span").text(data['wish']);
                    $(".box no-border").hide();
                    $("#cart-danger").show();
                    
                    $("#cart_icon_" + data["website_id"]).attr("src","{{URL::asset('assets/images/far-fa-shopping-cart.png')}}");
                    $("#cart_icon_" + data["website_id"]).removeClass('filled_cart');
                    $("#cart_icon_" + data["website_id"]).addClass('blank_cart');
                    
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('#cart-danger').hide();
                    }, 1500);
                    }

                    $("#cart_span").show();
                    $("#wishlist_span").show();

                    if (data['wish'] == 0) {
                         $("#wishlist_span").css("display", "none");
                    }
                    if (data['carts'] == 0) {
                         $("#cart_span").css("display", "none");
                    }

                }, error: function (error) {
                    alert("Something went wrong please try again.");
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! Could you share you're code and explain what you've tried so far? What are you using (Vue, React, Svelte, Angular, etc)?

Comment: Hi, and thanks.
this can be solved if I reload my page after pressing the back button it shows double reload.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!!window.performance && window.performance.navigation.type == 2){
window.location.reload();}
```

this will not reload your page two times and you will also get updated data after clicking the back button.

Answer (score 0):

This should work properly on all browsers

```js
// force browser to refresh when you click on previous or next button arrow of browser

window.addEventListener( "pageshow", function ( event ) {
  var historyTraversal = event.persisted || 
                         ( typeof window.performance != "undefined" && 
                              window.performance.navigation.type === 2 );
  if ( historyTraversal ) {
    // Handle page restore.
    window.location.reload();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After:

```js
success: function(data) {
  if (action == "add") {
    window.location.reload();
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you prefer to avoid page reloading, you can opt to receive JSON data in response to this request, which contains the updated information. You can then assign and display this data. If feasible, you could also reuse the initial data you sent to update the view.